# How to read the local DNS cache contents?

Tags: linux, dns, cache

I know that on Windows I can issue `ipconfig /displaydns` and I see the local DNS's cache content.

How can I list the DNS's cache content in Linux?

I would like to get as much as cross-distro solution as possible.

Comment: As far as I am aware, there is no DNS cache maintained on the client in Linux (resolver) unless the system is using local caching only dns service on the client.

Comment: You always have the `/etc/hosts` file which may contain entries generated by DNS blacklisting services.

Answer (score 25):

### Prior to `systemd`, there was almost no OS-level DNS caching

Prior to `systemd` there was no OS-level DNS caching on Linux (and probably most Unix), unless [`nscd`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/nscd) or [`dnsmasq`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/dnsmasq) was installed and running.

Even then, the DNS caching feature of `nscd` was disabled by default in Debian at least, simply because [it is broken](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=335476).

As for `dnsmasq`, the [caching seems to occur in RAM](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/163075/39845) by default.

Comment: A lot of systems these days use `dnsmasq` by default so https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/162973/79839 could be useful.

Comment: And *these* days, anything using `systemd` will likely have `systemd-resolved` running by default which does cache DNS results based on their TTL

Answer (score 9):

`nscd` is the Name Service Caching Daemon.  This is the utility that Linux, Solaris, and other use to cache name service lookups.  Name Service in this case is a generic term, not strictly limited to host resolution, but also users, groups, etc.

I don't know of a way to see the actual contents of the cache, though you can display statistics with `/usr/sbin/nscd -g`.

That can at least show you how efficient your cache is, though not exactly what it's resolving.

You may have other options if you're using an alternate caching tool, like DNSMASQ.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using `nscd`, you can view the contents (and possibly some other garbage), by showing the ASCII strings from the binary cache file.  In Debian/Ubuntu, that file is `/var/cache/nscd/hosts` for the hosts/DNS cache, so you can run `strings /var/cache/nscd/hosts` to see the hosts in cache.

Note that this is a total hack as there is seemingly no proper way to inspect the `nscd` cache without decoding the binary format.

Comment: `strings /var/cache/nscd/hosts | sort | uniq` works well

Comment: Mine appears under `/var/db/nscd/hosts` (but not readable except by root)

Answer (score 3):

You can send SIGUSR1 to systemd-resolved process to view the cache with journalctl.

`killall -USR1 systemd-resolved && journalctl -u systemd-resolved | grep -A 100000 "CACHE:"`