# How do I clear the dns cache on centos7 and centos8?

Tags: centos, dns, cache, libvirt

I am working on scripting a way to flush dns cache on different linux distros. I want to support doing this with Ubuntu-server, Ubuntu-desktop, Centos8-desktop, and Centos7-server(nogui)

I have built 4 vms of each.

For ubuntu its easy. I can just run `sudo systemd-resolve --flush-caches` and that does the trick.

However for the centos distros I cant seem to find a way to accomplish clearing the cache or even understanding how DNS is working. What I have read online is that for centos/rhel I can use either `dnsmasq` or `nscd` based off [this link](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/5855741), but my results are different...

On the centos8 box, I found the `dnsmasq` service was stopped and disabled after deployment. Trying to start service gave an error that port 53 was taken. I looked up `ss -tulpn` and found that port 53 was taken by virb0 interface, which is apart of `libvirtd`. IT seems kvm is installed by default in centos8 stream? Either way I am curious how dns / caching even works with this service enabled. How do I clear a cache on a centos host that has libvirtd enabled?

On the cnetos7 box, I found no `dnsmasq` or `nscd` service. So I am kind of puzzled how dns caching even works at all?

How can I determine how dns is cached on the centos8 and centos7 hosts. How do I look at the current dns cache? and how do I clear the cache?

Note I have two `nameserver` configured in my `/etc/resolve` on each centos box.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with command (as `root`):

```
resolvectl flush-caches
```

If you have `nscd` just restart it.
Also check if you have AD bind and `sssd` can cache some records.

Comment: That does not work, anything systemd-resolve or resolvectl on these boxes gives the following error

`Failed to flush caches: Unit dbus-org.freedesktop.resolve1.service not found.`

Comment: @Dave, IMHO in such case you do not have any DNS cache.

Comment: @Dave, if you have AD bind check also `sssd`

Comment: hmmm more resarch, I found this post https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1855252. I tried enabling `systemd-resolved.service` and that worked! I can now use `resolvectl flush-caches`. Not so much on the centos7 box. Why the hell wouldn't that service be enabled out of the box? Weird.

Comment: @Dave I assume it's not enabled as most people will be using bind/named or using a local dns system. I would be really hacked of if it was enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, dns caching does not appear to be enabled by default on centos7 and centos8.

Ok so I found [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28553/how-to-read-the-local-dns-cache-contents) and it details what I thought. Without systemd there was no dns caching on linux boxes. There were two alternative options which were `nscd` service or `dnsmasq`. It seems nscd was flaky and not found on newer boxes. `dnsmasq` was no included by default on all boxes so that would need to be installed and enabled.

I was able to get the centos8 box to work based off [this post](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1855252). It seems dnsmasq, libvirt, and systemd-resolve are all installed. But none of them are really enabled to do the work of caching. It needs to be enabled manually. After I `systemctl start systemd-resolved.service` and `systemctl enable systemd-resolved.service` that fixed the centos8 box.

The centos7 box has nothing on it to enable caching. So I will have to figure out how to set that up. Probabbly will set up systemd-resolved to stay normalized with NetworkManager, systemd, and todays trends.